# How do I programmatically make images black-and-white-filtered?

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to make images black-and-white-filtered programmatically in React Native? I have a few images with white backgrounds and colored letters on them. I want those letters to be all black, so that they stand out easily.

Comment: may be it will help you :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-filter-kit

Comment: Thanks. But, what I want is to save the image in the devices' cache folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Hi @Jinwook Kim,

You need to `style` prop to apply a grayscale filter to the image. Here is an example of how you could do this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    filter: 'grayscale(100%)',  // You can adjust the intensity of the grayscale accoding. value of 0% will produce a normal images.
  },
});
```

> the grayscale(100%) filter in the Image component, which will make black and white.

```js
const MyImage = () => {
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('./my-image.png')}
      style={styles.image}
    />
  );
};

export default MyImage;
```

Comment: Then how can I save the image in the device? I need to use the image to recognize the letters on it via OCR libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But, if you want to save image into your device, then you can use module called ```react-native-fs```. @Jinwook Kim

Comment: Here is some documentation. That help you to understanding that module :- [**react-native-fs**](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-access-file-systems-react-native/)

Comment: Here is the example I get from internet. Its good one:-
```const imagePath = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/my-image.jpg`;

RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, imageData, 'base64')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('The image was saved to the device!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: It's save your image in **cache directory** @JinwookKim